# how can i pass two different files names for two copy activities in adf pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

Actually i am loading the data through incremental load in ADF. Then I am using the if condition to check the load whether it is a full load or a incremental load. In the if condition i am having 2 copy activities in which true activity is a incremental load and the false activity is a full load.but when i am passing the parameters to two different copy activities i am unable to pass two different file names but without using stored procedures

i need to get the two different values for the two different parametes.so how can i get it

Answer (score 0):

> i am unable to pass two different file names but without using stored procedures

You can use dataset parameters for the file names.

This is a sample demonstration.

Create a dataset parameter named `filename` in the dataset and give that in the file path of the dataset as dynamic content.

[image]

Here, you can create another parameter for your folder also if your source files paths are different.

Then in the copy activity of if True activities, give your file name in the parameter for incremental load.

[image]

For Full load copy activity, give the respective file name.

[image]

Based on your if condition, this will take the respective file for copy.

Here my source data is from storage account and if your source is a database, then also you can create the dataset parameter for the table name.